# Camera rotation calculation?

Tags: java, opengl-es, camera, rotation

i wanted to tranlate camera in world space. It doesn`t move as i expected. My Algorithm is

1. first i translate the camera in View space.
   Camera is always located in (0,0,0). After i calculate the new camera location points in viewspace.Then I multiply the points with inverse view matrix, So i thought i would get the camera location in the world space.
2. second i calculate the new view matrix
   Then i calculate the view matrix by using setLookAtM function of OpenGL. and set the new viewmatrix.

but my problem is its new locations couldn`t be calculated. Its values are NAN

here is my code.

```
private void pivotRotation(double angle,int[] pivot, double distance){
    float[] temp = new float[4];
    float[] temp2 = new float[4];

    float[] extObj = new float[16];     
    float[] startPointsOnViewSpace = new float[4];
    float[] newEyeOrigin = new float[4];
    float[] newLookOrigin = new float[4];

    int[] viewport = new int[16];

    viewport[0] = 0;
    viewport[1] = 0;
    viewport[2] = (int)myRenderer.screenWidth;
    viewport[3] = (int)myRenderer.screenHeight;

    int[] newEye = new int[2];
    newEye[0] = (int)((pivot[0] + ((viewport[2]/2) - pivot[0]) * Math.cos(angle)  - ((viewport[3]/2) - pivot[1]) * Math.sin(angle)));
    newEye[1] = (int)((pivot[1] + ((viewport[2]/2) - pivot[0]) * Math.sin(angle)  + ((viewport[3]/2) - pivot[1]) * Math.cos(angle)));

    GLU.gluUnProject((float)newEye[0], (float)(viewport[3] - newEye[1]), 0.0f, myRenderer.modelViewMatrix, 0, myRenderer.projectionMatrix, 0, viewport, 0, extObj, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMV(startPointsOnViewSpace, 0, myRenderer.modelViewMatrix, 0, extObj, 0);
            // new camera location in viewspace
    startPointsOnViewSpace[0] /= startPointsOnViewSpace[3]; 
    startPointsOnViewSpace[1] /= startPointsOnViewSpace[3];
    startPointsOnViewSpace[2] /= startPointsOnViewSpace[3];


    newEyeOrigin[0] = startPointsOnViewSpace[0];   
    newEyeOrigin[1] = startPointsOnViewSpace[1];
    newEyeOrigin[2] += distance / pinchParameter;
    newEyeOrigin[3] = 1.0f;

    newLookOrigin[0] = newEyeOrigin[0]; 
    newLookOrigin[1] = newEyeOrigin[1];
    newLookOrigin[2] = newEyeOrigin[2] - 1.0f;
    newLookOrigin[3] = 1.0f;
    // temp[0], temp[1], temp[2] are new camera location in the world space. i think
    Matrix.multiplyMV(temp, 0, myRenderer.inverseViewMatrix, 0, newEyeOrigin, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMV(temp2, 0, myRenderer.inverseViewMatrix, 0, newLookOrigin, 0);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        myRenderer.eyeLocation[i] = temp[i];
        myRenderer.lookPosition[i] = temp2[i];
    }

    myRenderer.eyeSettings();
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using gluLookAt()?  It's pretty handy for handling all of these transformations.  Here's some help (http://www.felixgers.de/teaching/jogl/gluLookAt.html)

Comment: @MaxFeldkamp tnanks for answering.
 in my case, i use opengles 2. And my shader use viewmatrix to render the scene. So i used setlookatm to get the viewmatrix.Anyway what is the difference between glulookat and setLookatM??. Both of them define the viewmatrix. I think something is wrong with my algorithm to calculate the new position of the camera.